# Mezzanine/TinyMCE filtering script type

Tags: tinymce, mezzanine, brython

I'm building a website using [brython](http://brython.info/) and I came by a problem that has nothign to do with it.

My problem is with Mezzanine or TinyMCE editor (I'm not sure which). To make brython work I need the script tag to be "text/python". But the editor filters it automatically to "text/javascript".

I disabled the filtering already, both in the admin panel and in the actual source code, I tried adding "text/python" to the RICHTEXT_ALLOWED defaults in the mezzanine configuration too.

Just to be clear, security is not an issue, this particular feature won't go online in the final version of the website.

Comment: Sorry - you are trying to input brython scripts through the editor, is that the isse? Or  is the problem about not being able to trigger some editor feature from Brython?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to input brython scripts through the editor, although this is not the "worst" problem. I'm more puzzled about why the editor doesn't let me change the type="text/javascript".

However, if there's a work around for the brython scripts I would like to hear too.

Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Although the HTML specification does allow one to put any value other than "text/javascript" in script's `type` attribute, few projects do that, and Brython is one of those few.  It is likely the "text/javascript" value is simply hardcoded in the editor and it won't allow you to change that.

(There is probably a big chance of having an issue closed as "won't fix/not a bug" or equivalent if you try to report this to the editor's issue tracker).

I think the workaround in this case is to write some javascript to change the text on the attribute on the relevant script tags to "text/python" *prior* to calling Brython.  i.e., instead of triggering Brython on your page with

`<body onload="brython()" >`

Do something along

`<body onload="function (){var x = document.getElementsByName("python"); for(var i=0; i < x.length; x++){x.type="text/python"};brython()}()" >`

(and of course, add the attribute `name='python'` to all your python script tags)

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. 

Thank you, I'll try your fix as soon as I can.